# Print chart from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, printing

**Is there a way to print a chart from Google Sheet with code?**

**Neatly without other objects, just one graph, one page.
And with prepared printing settings.**

I've tried different ways, they don't work. 
I tried templated html with Javascript `window.print()` method and it processes only current window (the sidebar + all buttons etc.) It just opens printing settings page.

My chart is Embedded chart type but if I need to change its type it's ok.

**I'd like to have printing settings page with all needed settings chosen (or even start printing) by the button click.**

Comment: Get the chart as pdf and feed it to Google cloud print api.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference how to accomplish that?

Comment: [#43](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753663#comment43) might help.

Comment: Thank you, I will study that.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the three dots in the top right of the chart.   Click "Download", choose pdf.   Save the PDF and print that.